# How to enable Multiple Date Select on DatePicker in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker

I have DatePickers currently set up in my project, I have 2 function for a start date DatePicker and an end date DatePicker and then returning the values of each to be checked (making sure end is not before the start and so on).

I would like to implement the ability to choose both start and end dates off a single DatePicker, an example can be seen in the booking android app.

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android component `DatePickerDialog` does not support such option but you can always implement your own custom implementation.

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45560625/5993410)

Answer (score 1):

By default, android datepicker won't support that. You can use [this](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) library for that, it is useful for your requirement, selecting a range of date/ showing a range of dates, disabling dates.